# How to structure Restful API client files in C# project?

Tags: c#, web-services

I've developed a Restful API in PHP, now the API makes different resources available like: `Article, User, Service, Trace etc...`.
I'm going to implement each resource in a portable DLL, so I can use the API method in each platform as Xamarin, XBox, Windows etc...
I want to ask how I should setup the structure of each DLL.
I'm thinking to use the following stack:

The project name within the solution is the name of the resource, for example `Article`.
Now I have a class called `Article`. The `Article` resource implements other sub-resources such as `Fam` and `List`.  So in the same DLL I can also use the method of other sub-resources.
In the solution, for simplicity, I separated each sub resource in their class as:

```
Article, Fam and List
```

My RestFull API makes these verbs available: `GET - DELETE - POST - PUT`. So in my DLL I've created 4 folders with the smen name as the available verbs.
In each folder, for example (GET), I have the class resource and sub_resources:

```
Article_GET, Fam_GET and List_GET
```

In the classes above I have only the GET method request.
In the main class, for example `Article` I implement all `GET - DELETE - POST - PUT` classes methods, little example:

```
public class Article_GET
{
        public class Article
        {
            public string codice { get; set; }
            public string descrizione { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Article> article { get; set; }
        }

        public List<Article> GetArticle()
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("json");
            return obj.article;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `Article` class:

```
public class Article
{
        public static List<Article_GET.Article> GetArticles()
        {
            return new Article_GET().GetArticle();
        }
}
```

so when I import the DLL that has this namespace: `CompanyName.Product.Article`
I can simply use: `Article.GetArticles();` or `Article.AddArticle()` etc...

Image stack example:

[image]

I don't know if is this a good stack classes hierarchy. Could someone tell me how I can improve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd rather organize my project by endpoint/resource than by method.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Each verb folder class have a method that call a resource. Maybe I misunderstood what do you mean?

Comment: A folder per resource and the different methods within that folder. Not the other way round.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Aside from that, do you think the overall structure is good? In particular creating a relative to the resource class for a type of verb?

Comment: For starters, read all the guidelines you can find starting here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And don't nest classes to group them, that's what namespaces are for.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it will eventually bite you in the behind, as in that it's very cluttered and doesnt really provide good maintainability.

I would have organized it like this:

---

Each resource (model) gets its own class file containing its attributes, like:

**Model/Article.cs**

- Id
- Name
- Price

---

Each resource collection has a class containing methods for handling that resource, like:

**Resources/Articles.cs**

- Get(int id)
- List()
- Update(int id, Article article)
- Delete(int id)
- Create(Article article)

---

Here is a dotnetfiddle example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YE1hc1

Comment: In fact it is already so. As you can see from my stack every resource has its own class file Article, Fam and List. Then I organized in folders GET, POST, PUT and DELETE classes containing requests for that verb. I think putting these methods into a single class would really be very bad to handle, as you suggested.

Comment: Well, I can't do more then to warn you, as it seems you will get a lot of duplicated code for nothing. It doesnt make sense out of a REST perspective either, as you've actually implemented state by separating each requst in its own class..

If you decide to keep it this way, which I strongly suggest you dont, you should atleast consider making abstract methods out of the requests and then implement them in each request class.

Comment: Just to better understand what you mean, you could post an example of how your solution should work? Type recalling Article.GetArticles ()?

Comment: I updated the answer with a dotnetfiddle.

Comment: Ok so you have declared one class Article and put inside of it all the sub-classes for the verbs: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. What's happean when the request to implement will more of 50s? Should I write all the method inside a single file? For this I've created separate classes for each verbs.

Comment: No, I have one model class named Article, and one collection class named ArticleS. And yes, I think you should put all the verbs in the collection class. What do you mean with "will more of 50s"? Hopefully, your collection class will only need one method for each of the common CRUD verbs + list. All logic except that should be placed in a separate class all together.

Comment: Exactly what I did. I've separated the classe verbs. Forum the 50s. Forum example I could have 10 methods get that return a different thing for the same resource. If I use your logic stack I'll have one file with a lot of methods..